# StringBuilder AppendFormat with dynamically params array

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, asp.net-core-6.0

I am dynamically building a SQL statement using StringBuilder. The criteria are defined by the user and there is no limit.

There is no problem with the string format, it is generated fine.

Let's say user defines 3 criterias.

The dynamically formatted string is: "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Field1 = '{0}' OR Field1 = '{1}') AND (Field2 = '{2}')"

Currently I have:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Field1 = '{0}' OR Field1 = '{1}') AND (Field2 = '{2}')", p[0], p[1], p[2]);
```

How can I add the array of parameters with a loop?

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < p.Count; i++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Field1 = '{0}' OR Field1 = '{1}') AND (Field2 = '{2}')", p[i]);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Using `StringBuilder`, you don't parameterize your query. Make sure, you sanitize your user input, or you are open to SQL Injection. Better: parameterize your query.

Comment: It is possible to build a query dynamically and use parameters. See [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?503298) for an example.

Comment: Crhistian, See this link: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql/from-sql#:~:text=a%20%27FromSqlRaw%27%20operation.%27-,DbSet.FromSqlRaw%20Parameterized%20Queries,-You%20are%20always

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can use [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0) to join `p` collection into a `string` with `", "` as a delimiter:

```
sb.Append($"Field1 in ({string.Join(", ", p)})");
```

or

```
sb.AppendFormat("Field1 in ({0})", string.Join(", ", p));
```

I've changed SQL syntax as well: `field1 in (p1, p2, ..., pn)` instead of `field1 = p1 or field1 = p2 or ... or field1 = pn`.

However, be careful with SQL building instead of using parameters (or bind variables): [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) can be a real problem.

Comment: While this answers the question, a hint to a **possible SQL injection** should be added.

Comment: What would the AppendFormat look like with the corrected formatted text?

Comment: @Federico: `sb.AppendFormat("Field1 in ({0})", string.Join(", ", p));`

Answer (score -1):

Although I haven't used string.join, based on **Dimitry's** idea of using a single placeholder I modified the code to concatenate the criteria into a single string, looking like this.

strWhere is the string generated dynamically with criteria.

```
strWhere = "(Field1 = value1 OR Field1 = value2) AND (Field2 = Value3)"
StringBuilder sqlRaw = new StringBuilder();
sqlRaw.AppendFormat("SELECT * FROM Fichas WHERE {0}", strWhere);
```

Thank you so much Dimitry for your help.